# Parse a bittorrent tracker announce response

Tags: python, python-3.x, bittorrent, tracker

I'm trying to get the peer list for a torrent from my tracker by parsing the repsonse to an announce request. This is how far I've gotten:

```
import sys,binascii,urllib.parse,urllib.request
from bcode import bdecode

def announce(inputurl):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(inputurl) as url:
        print(url.read())
        decoded = bdecode(url.read())
        print(decoded)

infohash = sys.argv[1] # Read info hash from command line

encoded_infohash = urllib.parse.quote(binascii.a2b_hex(infohash)) # Encode inf_hash
announce_url = "http://my_tracker_ip:6969/announce?info_hash=" + encoded_infohash
announce(announce_url)
```

This produces the following error when I run it for the info_hash of a sample torrent:

```
b'd8:completei1e10:downloadedi2e10:incompletei3e8:intervali1698e12:min intervali849e5:peers24:\x89?GZ\xc4\x0f\xb8K\xd5r\xc4\x0f\xc0\xa8\x00\t\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x00\x01\xe8\x8ce'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "announce.py", line 15, in <module>
    announce(announce_url)
  File "announce.py", line 7, in announce
    decoded = bdecode(url.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bcode.py", line 55, in bdecode
    if input[0] == 'i':
IndexError: index out of range
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm using Python 3.4.3

Comment: @micgeronimo look better, there's no problem with args. stack trace triggered on announce function call. About `requests` - it's just a sugar, `urllib` could do the job perfectly fine without installing any new module. Next, it's unclear why OP need to use BeautifulSoup, tracker doesn't generate html responses so you answer is completely useless.

Comment: @Reishin Agreed, I'm fairly sure that's not the problem. @micgeronimo The error message doesn't say that it's missing `sys.argv[1]`. It successfully prints the `url.read()` response, which means it got that far successfully, and if I ask it to print the `announce_url` variable that succeeds too. The 'index out of range' seems to happen once the `url.read()` response is passed to bdecode.

Comment: about the problem, you get byte encoded string as an response, i don't known which param type expect bencode, but i suggest string. Please try `url.read().decode(<codepage>)` Example: decoded = bdecode(url.read().decode('utf-8'))

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Decode to utf-8 seems to fail and I get the same error. Just trying to use `decode('utf-8')` on the byte encoded string without the rest of the script produces `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 92: invalid start byte`.

Comment: Theory wiki for BitTorrent specification [https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Response] indicates that the tracker response should be a bedcoded dictionary. bcode documentation [https://github.com/medecau/bcode] says it converts bencoded strings to python values. Maybe the problem is trying to pass a bencoded dictionary rather than just a string.

Comment: Actually looking at the specification for bencoding [https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding] it's pretty easy to read the string without decoding it. The only bit I don't understand is the last string/key in the dictionary which seems to be further encoded (with lots of \x).

Comment: Is that final string/key (24:\x89?GZ\xc4\x0f\xb8K\xd5r\xc4\x0f\xc0\xa8\x00\t\x00\x00\xc0\xa8\x00\x01\xe8\x8c) maybe what the BitTorrent specification refers to at the peers(binary model). If so then it is probably the IP address(es) and port number(s) encoded in network (big endian) notation. If that's the case how can I decode the string?

Comment: The peer list is in compact format. See: BEP23 - Tracker Returns Compact Peer Lists http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html

Comment: @Encombe Thank-you for your comment. Can you explain how I use the compact format string (ie how do I 'un-compact it')? My tracker seems not to support `compact=0`, as I get an 'HTTP Error 400' when I try to use it.

Comment: just as the BEP says, `N*<4 bytes IP, 2 bytes port>`, in network byte order. so you got to do some binary processing.

Comment: Thanks @the8472. I'm having trouble figuring out the binary processing. I get that the two characters after each \x represent a byte in hexadecimal, but what's the significance of the '?GZ', the capital 'K', and the '\t' in the string?

Comment: I don't know any python, but you're looking at binary data that has been mangled through layers of character-set-encoding (utf-8/iso8891/whatever) and console output. You probably should look at the hex output of just the `peers` value, *after* bdecoding. or at least open the raw response (dumped to a file) in a hex editor if you want to inspect it manually.